# SSL in OSX in webAPI ASP.NET Core

Tags: macos, ssl, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-mac

When I test my webAPI Asp.NEt Core 2 in Visual Studio in Windows with SSL enabled I see this

[image: IIS Express]

And all works fine

[image: localhost redirected]

[image: api working]

I open this application in VS 2019 for Mac and when I start it the url is http://localhost:5001 instead https://localhost:44313

[image]

Anyway, How do I have this in the Configure method in Starup.cs

.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps(301,44313))

This request http://localhost:5501/api/proyectos is translated to https://localhost:44313/api/proyectos but here in OSX fails

[image: error]

How can I see the server of my webAPI in OSX?

This in local environment only works with IIS Express?

Any idea Please?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work from the command line using dotnet run?

Comment: No. The same error

Comment: Might be worth trying to re-generate the local developer certs by running `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` then running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` and then see if dotnet run works. More detailed instructions on resolving ssl issues can be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#all-platforms---certificate-not-trusted